# Changing all elements of list by accident

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm new to C# programming, and for first time I ran into unexpected behaviour of code that I can't solve.

```
List<int[]> snakeCoords = new List<int[]>();
snakeCoords.Add(new int[2] { 25, 10 });
int direction = 0;
while (true)
{
    Move(direction);
}
void Move(int direction)
{
    int[] headCoords = new int[2];
    headCoords = snakeCoords.Last();

    switch (direction)
    {
        case 0:
            headCoords[1]--;
            snakeCoords.Add(headCoords);
            break;

    }
```

This code is an extraction I put into `Main{}`, so there is no influences by anything else, still it doesn't work. Result is snakeCoords.Count = number of iterations, where every single element of list is {25, (10 - number of iterations) }. The result I expect and want is list of elements like {25,10}, {25,9}, {25,8}, etc.
I can think of some workarounds, but I really want to understand what this code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You throw away the `new int[2]` you assign to `headCoords` and overwrite it with the array already in the list. In other words, in the end you have 10 entries of the **same** array in the list, so each modification is reflected in all entries, because you are modifying one and the same array each time.

Make sure you **copy** or **clone** the array, or copy the values in the array to a new array, instead of reusing the same array again and again.

The fix would be replacing

```
int[] headCoords = new int[2];
headCoords = snakeCoords.Last();
```

with

```
int[] headCoords = (int[]) snakeCoords.Last().Clone();
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot Array is reference data type so i have to use proper methods to handle values. I considered once that i pass reference, but i failed to think it through code. Lesson learnt: dont think, check docs .
Also thank you for editing my post, so next time i can make it in correct way. I hope my next question is going to be way less dumb.